# Is there some way to browse erlang term storage (ETS)

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I've got a small Elixir app that is using erlang term storage, and I'd like to browse it and see what's being stored. Is there some way to do that with either Elixir or Erlang?

I'd like to see how big it's getting and what's inside.

Edit: I know that I can look at the processes with `:observer.start`, but there isn't a process or application that is listed as `ets`. There is `Elixir.Hex.Registry.ETS`, but the state or other process information doesn't look like it's the right thing.

I can also print things out in `iex` however, that is not a great experience.

Comment: http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#all-0

Comment: @mudasobwa That's a cool function, but it's not great for browsing or exploring the data.

Comment: Why has the question been downvoted if there is an answer that has been upvoted? The question must not be that bad if we have a similar question and end up here and the answer helps us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned previously, you can use `Observer`. To view ETS tables, click on `Table Viewer` tab, then select the table you need and with a right click you get the option to either view `Table Info` or `Show Table Content`.

To start the observer, run:

```
:observer.start
```

---

Screenshot:

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: It looks like this doesn't include all the tables. I can see more tables when I run `:ets.all` in `iex`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That's the default behaviour of observer. 
from doc
`By default, ETS tables are displayed whereas unreadable private ETS tables and tables created by OTP applications are not diplayed. Use menu View to view "system" ETS tables, unreadable ETS tables, or Mnesia tables.`
http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html#id57236

Answer (score 1):

ets:i/1 is an interactive way to browse tables:

http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#i-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Observer application for that. It can display many different things, including the contents of ETS tables.  Start it by typing in the Elixir shell:

```
:observer.start
```

Or in the Erlang shell:

```
observer:start().
```

For this to work, Erlang must have been built with the WX library.

There is some documentation in the [Observer User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html#id57236).  Also, [this blog post](https://tkowal.wordpress.com/2016/04/23/observer-in-erlangelixir-release/) describes how to use Observer to observe a remote Elixir node, which is advisable for production systems.

Comment: So, I can start :observer and it lists the applications and processes, but ETS isn't listed in there, at least not as such. I'll update the question to be clearer.